# DELETE function not deleting

Tags: reactjs, express

This is my first time doing CRUD function using MERN stack. I'm having problem implementing DELETE request. Hopefully someone could help me find out where the problem is.

Server route & controller

```
router.delete("/posts/:id", verifyToken, deletePost);

export const deletePost = async (req, res) => {
  const { id } = req.params;
  try {
    await Post.findByIdAndRemove(id);
    res.status(200).json({ message: "Post deleted successfully." });
  } catch (error) {
    console.error(error);
    res.status(404).json({ message: error.message });
  }
};
```

React Redux reducer

```
deletePost: (state, action) => {
      state.posts = state.posts.filter((post) => post._id !== action.payload);
    },
```

Fetch API & dispatch:

```
const PostWidget = ({
  postId,
  postUserId,
  name,
  description,
  location,
  picturePath,
  userPicturePath,
  likes,
  comments,
}) => {
...
const handleDelete = async () => {
    try {
      const response = await fetch(
        `${process.env.REACT_APP_API_URL}/posts/${postId}`,
        {
          method: "DELETE",
          headers: {
            Authorization: `Bearer ${token}`,
            "Content-Type": "application/json",
          },
        }
      );
      const result = await response.json();

      if (response.ok) {
        dispatch(deletePost({ post: result }));
      }
    } catch (err) {
      console.log(err.message);
    }
  };
...
return (
<IconButton onClick={handleDelete}>
   <DeleteOutlined />
</IconButton>
)
}
```

When click on the delete icon, the Network shows the DELETE request is OK. But nothing happened at frontend. No "Post deleted successfully." message showed at console either.

I saw some tutorial saying id has to be used in handleDelete function, but I didn't put postId in handleDelete function like below.

```
const handleDelete = async (postId) => {}


<IconButton onClick={() => handleDelete(postId)}>
   <DeleteOutlined />
</IconButton>
```

It would start endless delete requests at backend. I have to force stop the server.

The action.payload is below as requested. Is it supposed to be like this?
[image: action.payload]

Can anyone tell me where the problem is? That would be much much appreciated!

Comment: so how did the `postId` getting passed if you just did `onClick={handleDelete}` ?

Comment: @KcH I've updated my code, I think the postId is from the destructing

Comment: Did you check the `action.payload` could you log it and add the result here ?

Comment: @KcH the result added. Not sure if it's supposed be like that. Delete request is working at server side. But I have to refresh the page.

Comment: @KcH it's fixed. I changed the payload to postId as suggested by the answer below

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Everything you have done is okay but you forget to pass `postId` to dispatch function instead passing `object` without `postId` and comparing the `object` with in `deletePost` will do nothing.

I am assuming `postId` in state is `number` or `string`.

In `handleDelete` function pass `postId` instead of `object` then we can receive it on `payload` in `reducer`

```
const handleDelete = async () => {
try {
    const response = await fetch(
    `${process.env.REACT_APP_API_URL}/posts/${postId}`,
    {
        method: "DELETE",
        headers: {
        Authorization: `Bearer ${token}`,
        "Content-Type": "application/json",
        },
    }
    );
    const result = await response.json();

    if (response.ok) {
       dispatch(deletePost(postId)); // pass id
    }
} catch (err) {
    console.log(err.message);
}
};
```